# Bootstrap 4 label alignment

Tags: forms, bootstrap-4

I need to align the first text of the label to left and the second to the right as:

```
    Text1       Text2
     ---------------
    |               |
     ---------------
```

I tried:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="res-add-1">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between"> 
                    <div>Text1</div>
                    <div>Text2</div>
                </div>
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="res-add-1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the two texts are positioned just after the other.

```
    Text1Text2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to add a width to `div.d-flex`. Now I do not know the general width each of your form elements will need, but the following snippet should show what I mean:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="res-add-1">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between" style="width:140px">
            <div>Word1</div>
            <div>Word2</div>
        </div>
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="res-add-1">
</div>
```

**Edit: Apply width to form-group label instead**

```
<style>
    .form-group label {
        width: 100%
    }
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="res-add-1">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <div>Text1</div>
                    <div>Text2</div>
                </div>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="res-add-1">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="res-add-1">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">    
                    <div>Text1</div>
                    <div>Text2</div>
                </div>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="res-add-1">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="res-add-1">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <div>Text1</div>
                    <div>Text2</div>
                </div>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="res-add-1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution worked. But, I have to specify a width... then it won't be responsive. I updated my question so that you can have an idea how I have placed the controls.

Comment: In that case, you will need instead, to define a style for .form-group label to occupy 100% width:
        .form-group label {
            width: 100%
        }
The actual width will be controlled by the parent column, which is already responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) Like this :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="res-add-1">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col">word 1</div>
         <div class="col">word 2</div>
          </div>           
        </div>
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="res-add-1">
</div>
```

Hope it helps !